# First Steps using Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

Im trying to implement arrays in order for my program to save any amount of data, an equivalent to C# for this

```
 int nT, i;
cTrabajador *apTrabajador;
do{
        cout<<"\t Indique el numero de Trabajadores: ";
        cin>>nT;
        }while(nT<=0||nT>=40);
        apTrabajador=new cTrabajador[nT];
for(i=0;i<nT;i++)
        apTrabajador[i].leer();/
        system("cls");
        cout<<"\t Lista de  Trabajadores"<<endl;
for(i=0;i<nT;i++)
        apTrabajador[i].imprimir ();
        delete[]apTrabajador;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
```

I used to program in C++, the program stores nT number of arrays in order to have all the data of the "trabajadores" so im Trying to make sense to the syntaxis i learned in C++ now in C# i would gladly welcome some help

Registro is a method in class that asks for data to the user, Imprimir is another method in the same class to print the stored data into the array

```
    namespace Poligono
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i,n;
            int[] Calculos;

            Console.WriteLine("\n Insert the number of items");
            string entry = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(entry, out n);
            Calculos = new int[n];

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
                 VolumenPrisma.Registro();      //needs to be stored in "n" arrays
                }
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
                 VolumenPrisma.Imprimir();      //needs to be stored in "n" 
                }
        }
    }
    }
```

/*    The class is */

```
namespace Poligono
{
public class VolumenPrisma
{
public static int Apotema, TamLado, NumLados, Altura, Lado;
public static int Perimetro, Area, Volumen;

public static int cPerimetro (int NumLados, int Lado){
    int P;
    P=(NumLados*Lado);
    return P;    
}

public static int cVolumen(int Area, int Altura)
{
    int V;
    V = Area * Altura;
    return V;
}

public static int cArea(int Perimetro, int Apotema)
{
    int A;
    A = (Perimetro * Apotema)/2;
    return A;
}

public static void Registro(){
        Console.WriteLine("Indique No. de lados: ");
        VolumenPrisma.Lado = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Indique tamanio de apotema: ");
        VolumenPrisma.Apotema = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());    

        Console.WriteLine("Indique tamanio de lado: ");
        VolumenPrisma.TamLado = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Indique la altura: ");
        VolumenPrisma.Altura = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

        Perimetro= cPerimetro(TamLado, Lado);   
        Area = cArea(Perimetro, Apotema);
        Volumen = cVolumen(Area, Altura);
}

public static void Imprimir() {
    Console.WriteLine("Lados= {0} ", Lado);
    Console.WriteLine("Tam Lado = {0} ", TamLado);
    Console.WriteLine("Apotema = {0} ", Apotema);
    Console.WriteLine("Perimetro = {0} ", Perimetro);
    Console.WriteLine("Area = {0} ", Area);
    Console.WriteLine("Volumen = {0} ", Volumen);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Last I checked, the type int has no italian/spanish/portuguese member functions ;) ``Calculos[i]`` is of type int. You probably want: ``Calculos[i] = VolumenPrisma.Registro()`` or something.

Comment: Registro() and imprimir() are both static methods,i skipped the class to make the code shorter  i will update the entry with a short example of th emethods

Comment: It would be much easier if you show us Registro() and imprimir(). BitTickler may also have the answer for you.

Comment: If `VolumenPrisma` is a static class, where `Registro()` and `Imprimir()` are static methods taking an int as parameter, the use would be `VolumenPrisma.Registro(Calculos[i]);`

Comment: Your trying to call a void method of a class. Change it from Calculos[i].VolumenPrisma.Registro();  to VolumenPrisma.Registro(); and the other one respectively. Thsoe 2 methods return void / nothing not an int.

Comment: @deathismyfriend that solves the problem  and makes it work, however im trying to implement arrays in the program

Comment: How are you trying to implement them ? Currently you aren't doing anything with the array. What would you like to do with it ?

Comment: im trying to store N numbers of arrays with the Registro() and Imprimir() functions, by using arrays meaning if the user inputs a 5 as N Registro should pop 5 times and then after the N=5 , it should print 5 times the stored values of the properties, and the calculated values

Comment: This wouldn't work on C++ either. Just saying.

Comment: @sstan added the c++ equivalent im trying to replicate in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need an array of instances of `VolumenPrisma` to work with, as you need to store somewhere the input data.

```
VolumenPrisma[] Calculos = new VolumenPrisma[n]();
```

Then you "register" (get the input parameters) these data by using:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Calculos[i] = new VolumenPrisma();    // create a new instance to store the data
    VolumenPrisma.Registro(Calculos[i]);      //get the parameters for this prisma
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    VolumenPrisma.Imprimir(Calculos[i]);      //Print results for that prisma
}
```

The full code would be like:

```
namespace Poligono
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, n;
            VolumenPrisma[] Calculos;

            Console.WriteLine("\n Insert the number of items");
            string entry = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(entry, out n);
            Calculos = new VolumenPrisma[n];

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Calculos[i] = new VolumenPrisma();    // create a new instance to store the data
                VolumenPrisma.Registro(Calculos[i]);      //get the parameters for this prisma
            }

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                VolumenPrisma.Imprimir(Calculos[i]);      //Print results for that prisma
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To work with static methods in VolumenPrisma class, you need to pass as parameter an instance of VolumenPrisma and modify the accesors for the instance fields.

```
public class VolumenPrisma
{
    public int Apotema, TamLado, NumLados, Altura, Lado;
    public int Perimetro, Area, Volumen;

    public VolumenPrisma()
    {
    }

    public static int cPerimetro (int NumLados, int Lado)
    {
        int P;
        P=(NumLados*Lado);
        return P;    
    }

    public static int cVolumen(int Area, int Altura)
    {
        int V;
        V = Area * Altura;
        return V;
    }

    public static int cArea(int Perimetro, int Apotema)
    {
        int A;
        A = (Perimetro * Apotema)/2;
        return A;
    }

    public static void Registro(VolumenPrisma prisma)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Indique No. de lados: ");
        prisma.Lado = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Indique tamanio de apotema: ");
        prisma.Apotema = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Indique tamanio de lado: ");
        prisma.TamLado = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Indique la altura: ");
        prisma.Altura = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

        prisma.Perimetro = cPerimetro(prisma.TamLado, prisma.Lado);
        prisma.Area = cArea(prisma.Perimetro, prisma.Apotema);
        prisma.Volumen = cVolumen(prisma.Area, prisma.Altura);
    }

public static void Imprimir(VolumenPrisma prisma) { 
        Console.WriteLine("Lados= {0} ", prisma.Lado);
        Console.WriteLine("Tam Lado = {0} ", prisma.TamLado);
        Console.WriteLine("Apotema = {0} ", prisma.Apotema);
        Console.WriteLine("Perimetro = {0} ", prisma.Perimetro);
        Console.WriteLine("Area = {0} ", prisma.Area); 
        Console.WriteLine("Volumen = {0} ", prisma.Volumen);
       }
}
```

But I agree all this sounds a bit weird, and it would be a lot easier to work with not static methods.

Comment: That's not going to work because `VolumenPrisma.Registro()` (and all the other members in that class)  is `static`.

Comment: @GoatZero remove the word `static` from all your code.

Comment: You don't need a workaround simply change from static to non static methods / variables.

Comment: removing the static, somehow messes up all my code and i cant acces the method and properties from the main

Comment: @GoatZero Added a solution to work with these methods as static.

Comment: @BlasSoriano Somehow every single line added to the main and every line added to with instance prisma pops an error 6 Member 'Poligono.VolumenPrisma.TamLado' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: Sorry, I'm opening my VisualStudio to fix that.

Comment: Registro() and Imprimir() get a No overload for method takes 0 arguments, and the line  Calculos = new VolumenPrisma[n](); expects a method

Comment: thanks for your time Im still trying to make sense about every change going on

Comment: @GoatZero Fixed all issues with static, tested in Visual Studio.

Comment: @BlasSoriano added an edit, i might aswell try removing the static from the methods and suggest another edit to make it easier to read, thanks a lot i think i get how to manage this for now